# Simple HTML DOM Parse Backwards

Tags: html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get the contents of the second to last  tags on a page. I cannot find it but was hoping it is possible to parse from bottom to top to look for the second  tag in that order rather than putting everything into an array and counting the one from last element. The reason to work backwards is that the page I am pulling from is dynamic and there can be hundreds of  tags which is more work than I want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to parse backwards so I used the following to do it by getting all the  tags in an array, get the total with count() and then access the array two less than the total number of elements.

```
$html = $datain->find('a');
$html_ind = $html[count($html)-2];
$result = $html_ind->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 1):

For any dynamic page, it must be 'static' the time you request, though it may change next time. It is no sense to parse the page in reverse order, and so far as i know, there is no reverse order parser algorithm for html page.

Here is my solution: in most case, dynamic page is also relatively 'static', the header of the page is always on top, and the footer is always at the bottom.

what you need to do is just find out the 'static' tag relates to the last but one.

suppose that you want to get the whole line of copyright information at the bottom of this stackoverflow page. This is a proper assumption，since the copyright information is nearly the second to last tag of this page, and this page is obviously dynamic.

i can find its id is: //*[@id="copyright"] (in fact it is a xpath, not an id, but it is not important here). you can just take a look at the source file of this page, or even more simply use tools such as firebug or digpage. And the id (xpath) is relatively 'static'.

When i am answering your question here, there is not any answer on this page. However, When you read this post, my answer is inserted into this page, and the page is surely changed. But, the xpath of the copyright information is still //*[@id="copyright"]. In other words, digpage still can gets the right tag for you.

Here is the copyright informatin i get from digpage before i submit the answer:

```
site design / logo © 2013 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc-wiki 
            with attribution required
```

you can try again by yourself (http://www.digpage.com/utility), it won't change.